# MediaWiki extension hiding in LibreOffice?

Tags: linux, libreoffice, wiki

I always used LibreOffice to write my MediaWiki-articles and saved it as MediaWiki .txt-file to use it on our Wiki. Since I upgraded my PC, I have the new LibreOffice 4.4.2.2, where it appears the MediaWiki-extension may not be included.  Am I just missing it?

I know, I could just write it into the MediaWiki-editor but it's not just about me, there are other people using the Wiki and it's too much for them to use the MediaWiki-syntax.

Answer (score 2):

Most of the time I use vim, as it has been my favorite editor (for me IDE) to edit text files and do programming stuff,

If you are using LibreOffice you can add the extension to it easily

Media wiki Libre office **[Extension](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/libreoffice-wiki-publisher/)**

Comment: Thanks for the link! Can you export files in vim for MediaWiki or do you have to type down the Wiki-syntax?

Comment: I do type mediawiki syntax